# Line goes from one vertex of rectangle to half of other side rule

Tags: rectangles

this question was on my test and I don't know which rule to apply to solve.
ABCD is a rectangle. Lines goes from A to half of other side and another line goes from D to half of other side OL is 2 cm. What is AO? An image is inserted below.

[image]

Comment: Um... your image link does not work.

Comment: and the sidelength of the rectangle?

Comment: we Need $a,b$ from the rectangle

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner sidelength wasn't given

Comment: This can be computed without knowing the side lengths. Look for similar triangles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Let $M$ be the midpoint of $\overline{AL}$. Then $\triangle{OLD}\sim\triangle{OMK}$, so $DL:KM::OL:OM$. By construction, $DL=\frac12DC$, $KM=\frac34CD$, and of course $AM=OM+OL$. I trust that you can complete the calculation from here.